# Generated congruence on monoids

Tags: category-theory, congruences, monoid

So, I'm currently reading "Category Theory for the Sciences" by David Spivak, and I'm having a little trouble understanding how congruences on monoids work.

Here's the definition, and a couple of propositions from the book:

> **Definition 4.1.1.17**
>
> Let $\mathcal{M} := (M, e, *)$ be a monoid. A congruence on $\mathcal{M}$ is an equivalente relation $\sim$ on $M$, such that for any $m, m' \in M$ and any $n, n' \in M$, if $m \sim m'$ and $n \sim n'$, then $m * n \sim m' \sim n'$.
>
> **Proposition 4.1.1.18**
>   Suppose that $\mathcal{M} := (M, e, *)$ is a monoid. Then the following facts hold:
>
> 1. Given any relation $R \subseteq M \times M$, there is a smallest congruence $S$ containing $R$. We call $S$ the congruence generated by $R$.
> 2. If $R = \emptyset$ and $\sim$ is the congruence it generates, then there is an isomorphism $M \overset{\cong}{\to} (M/\sim)$.

It's the second proposition I don't get. I came up with a concrete example to try to make sense of it, to no avail:

Let $M := \mathbb{Z}$, $e := 0$, and $*:= +$ (integer addition).

For $\sim$ to be a congruence on $M$, then $m * n \sim m' \sim n'$ must hold for any $m \sim m'$ and $n \sim n'$

So, for $m = m' := 2$ and $n = n' := 3$, we have:
$2 * 3 = 5 \sim 2 \sim 3$

Therefore, the congruence $\sim$ must contain the pairs: (2, 2), (3, 3), (5, 5), (2, 3), (3, 2), (2, 5), (5, 2), (3, 5), (5, 3), and the 
quotient $M/\sim$ must contain the equivalence class $\{2,3,5\}$. If this is so, how can there be an isomorphism $M \overset{\cong}{\to} (M/\sim)$? What did I miss?

Please bear in mind I'm still learning, so a simple explanation would be very much appreciated.

Comment: As to the second part of the proposition, am I wrong to think the smallest congruence containing $R=\phi$ is $\sim=\phi$? In that case the quotient $M/\sim$ identifies with $M$ because you're not making any identifications..

Comment: Looks like there might be a typo in the book - it should be: $$m*n\sim m'*n',$$ not $m*n\sim m'\sim n'$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews oooh, that makes a lot more sense! I double checked just to be sure, and yup, it does say $m * n \sim m' \sim n'$ in both the print version and the ebook.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that in the HTML version of the book, too. Couldn't find an errata list for the book.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think I found the [errata](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1J2AGqTTBRenZyeUnFvCbXnFVjK5zzEFzMRS245M4wAc/edit) ([linked from this site](http://cat.boffosocko.com/textbooks/)), and it seems to have an entry for this already, on the last page. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, that's a horrible document, but I guess it is better than nothing. @dcastro

Comment: You can find the book in gen.lib.rus.ec

Comment: @PtF If I understand things correctly, according to Thomas' correction, the smallest congruence should be the same as the smallest equivalence relation on $M$, which would be $\{ (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3) ... \}$, since equivalence is reflexive. And yeah, the isomorphism between $M$ and $M/\sim$ holds now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is the definition in the book, it is wrong. It should be:

$$m*n\sim m'*n'$$

not $m*n\sim m'\sim n'$.

Probably a typesetting error.

Comment: (+1) It is equivalent also with invariance by left and right translations.